# PHP block after html not executing

Tags: php, html

I have two blocks of code in the body section of an html ( .php) document. The code block before my heading executes, but the block after the heading does not. I've tried `phpinfo();` in the first block and it runs fine. Try it in the second block and it doesn't. I have no idea why this could be. If anyone has suggestions I'm all ears.

I'm currently running xampp on a windows machine.

```
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['ProfileID'])){
    echo "<div style='text-align: right'>" 
    . "<a href='CZSN_Login.php'>Log " 
    . "Out</a></div>\n";
}
//here phpinfo() executes
?>
<h1>Chinese Zodiac Social Network</h1>
<?php
require_once("Includes/inc_ChineseZodiacDB.php");
//here phpinfo() will not execute
if (isset($_SESSION['ProfileID'])){
    echo "<h2>Member Pages</h2>\n"; 
echo"<p>Below is a list of the members of the Chinese Zodiac Social"
        . "Network. Click on a member's name to view that member's detailed information" 
        . "You may also choose to <a href='CZSN_MyProfile.php'>update your profile</a>.</p>\n";
    $SQLQuery="select first_name, last_name, user_name "
        . "from zodiac_profiles order by "
        . "last_name, first name, user_name;";
    $result=$DBConnect->query($SQLQuery);
    if ($result===false){
        echo $ErrorMsgs[];  
    }
    else{
        //This should never happen, but we can check anyway.
        if ($result->num_rows==0){
            echo "<p>There are no members to show.</p>\n";  
        }
```

Here is the code in my inc_ChineseZodiacDB.php file:

```
<?php
$ErrorMsgs = array();
$DBConnect = @new msqli("localhost", "root", "password", "chinese_zodiac");
if ($DBConnect->connect_error)
    $ErrorMsgs[] = "The database server is not available." 
        . "Connect Error is " 
        . $mysqli->connect_errno 
        . " " . $mysqli->connect_error . ".";
?>
```

Comment: did you get any error? to enable php error reporting, add error_reporting(E_ALL) and init_set('display_errors') top of your code and run your file. now, did you see any error?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors. The output is simply the h1 between the two code blocks.

Comment: you have said second block not executed, if you getting only <h1> markup then first block also not working. isn't?

Comment: phpinfo() will execute in the first block. right now the if statement will not evaluate true, so I used phpinfo() at the end of the first block to see if it would work, and it does.

Comment: @brock and if you comment the line `require_once("Includes/inc_ChineseZodiacDB.php");` does it print the phpinfo?

Comment: I'm willing to bet it's because you have `session_start()` or are using a `header()` function within `inc_ChineseZodiacDB` which cannot be started because you've already sent data to the page.

Comment: @Prix Yes it prints phpinfo if I comment the require_once.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I do have a session_start(), but its at the very top of the file before the header. Not quite grasping why that would cause problems. I need a session for the page to work properly.

Comment: To clarify, the session_start() is at the top of this file, not the `inc_ChineseZodiacDB.php` file.

Comment: I found the issue. In the `inc_ChineseZodiacDB.php` file I had a typo in the database name, but for some reason it's not throwing my connection failure message.

Comment: @brock unhappily we cannot read your mind to see what is on that file so unless you post it we wont be able to tell you what is wrong, make sure to remove any sensitive information such as password or usernames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the ultimate problem. in the include file it reads:

```
<?php
$ErrorMsgs = array();
$DBConnect = @new msqli("localhost", "root", "password", "chinese_zodiac");
if ($DBConnect->connect_error)
    $ErrorMsgs[] = "The database server is not available." 
        . "Connect Error is " 
        . $mysqli->connect_errno 
        . " " . $mysqli->connect_error . ".";

?>
```

where it should read:

```
<?php
$ErrorMsgs = array();
$DBConnect = @new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "chinese_zodiac");
if ($DBConnect->connect_error)
    $ErrorMsgs[] = "The database server is not available." 
        . "Connect Error is " 
        . $mysqli->connect_errno 
        . " " . $mysqli->connect_error . ".";

?>
```

Note, I was calling `msqli` rather than `mysqli`. One simple typo...I'm still not understanding why the error messages were not being thrown for calling an undefined function. I added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of the file as well, and still no errors thrown. Either way, it works now. Thank you to everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching in **require_once ("Includes / inc_ChineseZodiacDB.php");** there can be triggered die() or exit();

Comment: I don't have any die() or exit() statements in that file, but I did find the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get "Error headers already sent", because of the title `<h1>Chinese Zodiac Social Network</h1>`. For `phpinfo()` to work there shouldn't be any output yet.

Comment: phpinfo() works if I comment out the `require_once` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the php tag in the `inc_ChineseZodiacDB` file (i.e. you have `?>` at the end of that file).

When your first file reads in the inc_ChineseZodiacDB file and sees the `?>`, it interprets that as the end of your php section of code, and all the other code after `require_once("Includes/inc_ChineseZodiacDB.php");` is ignored and read as regular html.

Remove that line, and your problem should be fixed:

```
<?php
$ErrorMsgs = array();
$DBConnect = @new msqli("localhost", "root", "password", "chinese_zodiac");
if ($DBConnect->connect_error)
    $ErrorMsgs[] = "The database server is not available." 
        . "Connect Error is " 
        . $mysqli->connect_errno 
        . " " . $mysqli->connect_error . ".";
```

Comment: I removed the closing line and it behaves the same.